# VC++ custom item template doesn't show up

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, itemtemplate

I tried making an item template. In the zip I put the files `module.cpp`, `module.h`, `module.ico` and `module.vstemplate`. The vstemplate file is:

```
<VSTemplate Type="Item" Version="2.0.0"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>C++ cpp/h pair (st)</Name>
        <Description></Description>
        <Icon>module.ico</Icon>
        <ProjectType>VisualC</ProjectType>
        <DefaultName>MyClass</DefaultName>
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
        <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cpp">module.cpp</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.h">module.h</ProjectItem>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

I copied this to the "custom item templates" dir (*not* the systemwide one): `Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates\VisualC\module.zip`

The VisualC folder wasn't there, I created it because I saw one called VisualC in the systemwide templates dir.

I've tried restarting VS. I also tried the "devenv /installvstemplates" thing just in case.

Comment: I'm curious to know if you ever found a solution to this. I've spent the last hour googling for this same problem and have come up with nothing.

Comment: Have you tried changing `<ProjectType>VisualC</ProjectType>` to `<ProjectType>VC</ProjectType>`? Not explicitly documented but that's what VC2012 uses for both project and item templates.

Comment: Alek's comment is the correct answer to this question.

Comment: No, whatever I do, nothing works. I can create custom items for C# or VB, but C++ (no matter if VisualC or VC) is ignored. Any ideas? Working with VS2013 though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small note on ItemTemplates page on MSDN:

> You cannot export templates for C++ projects.

Fortunately there is a solution, but much more complex than you expect.
Search MSDN for Visual C++ Wizards (sorry reputation too low to paste more links).

Starting point could be:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/96xz4cw2(v=vs.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730846(VS.80).aspx